# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i got a Problem with this following Code:

```
string name = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["name"];
names.Add(name);
InitializeComponent();
List.ItemsSource = names;
```

by:

```
string name = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["name"];
```

i got the error message:

> An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

The Code is in C#.
I try to use an Variabel from the othe Page.
How can i ask if the variable is "Not found" that the app jump to the other Page?
How can i solve the Problem?

Comment: I suppose it says what it is - there is no key which is "name"

Comment: I think that we're going to need more information here. Could you please provide a bit more context, perhaps a [small self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Also, which programming language is this? Please tag your question to indicate this, as it will make it easier for other users to find/answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to know whether the key exists before reading it, you can use the `ContainsKey` method:

```
if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("name"))
{
    string name = (string)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["name"];
    names.Add(name);
    InitializeComponent();
    List.ItemsSource = names;
}
else
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Also, you seem to want to navigate to another page when the key isn't found. The call to `InitializeComponent` shows that you're executing the code in the page constructor. If you try to use the NavigationService from the constructor, you will have a NullReferenceException. Move the code to the `Loaded` event, or override the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

Comment: Yeah that i search!
Thanks!