# C#, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I'm having an error in opening a connection

```
 public bool Open()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();// in this line I have an error
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I have these errors:

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll

Additional INFO:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

OUTPUT:

> 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\bin\Debug\POS.vshost.exe'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread 0x28b8 has exited with code 259
> (0x103). The thread 0x2d2c has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread
> 0xc0c has exited with code 259 (0x103). 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR
> v4.0.30319: POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\bin\Debug\POS.exe'. Symbols
> loaded. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.dll'. Cannot
> find or open the PDB file. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'.
> Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'POS.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
> POS.vshost.exe): Loaded
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'.
> Cannot find or open the PDB file. A first chance exception of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
> exceptionPOS.vshost.exeSystem.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException,
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089The given key
> was not present in the dictionary.   at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at POS.Class.DBConnect.Open() in c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Class\DBConnect.cs:line 35    at POS.Class.Globals..ctor() in c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Class\Globals.cs:line 26    at POS.Forms.frm_Main..ctor() in c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Forms\frm_Main.cs:line 20    at POS.Program.Main() in c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Program.cs:line 20    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version,
> String CharSetName)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version,
> String CharSetName)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at
> POS.Class.DBConnect.Open() in
> c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Class\DBConnect.cs:line 35    at
> POS.Class.Globals..ctor() in
> c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Class\Globals.cs:line 26    at
> POS.Forms.frm_Main..ctor() in
> c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Forms\frm_Main.cs:line 20    at
> POS.Program.Main() in
> c:\Users\JB\Desktop\Program\POS\POS\Program.cs:line 20    at
> System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
> args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
> Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
> The program '[11984] POS.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1
> (0xffffffff).

CONNECTION STRING:

> Server=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=pos;User Id=root;Password=;Allow Zero
> Datetime=true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146947/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-in-windows-phone)

Comment: I read that before I post a question. I don't understand so I post another question and I think that we have the same error because in my case is different

Comment: The code mentioned by demonplus references a windows phone application and  a dictionary that shows user state, which is different that your MySqlException refernces a DB call.  Does this help? https://www.saotn.org/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-with-mysql-connector-net-and-utf8mb4-character-set/

Comment: I will try thanks for the info you share @wesreitz

Comment: Is there a stack associated with the exception. Don't forget that other people's code (like the code behind the `connection.Open` call) are going to using things like Dictionaries

Comment: Show the connection string

Comment: Show connection string and full stack trace of the exception

Comment: This is my connection string (Server=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=pos;User Id=root;Password=;Allow Zero Datetime=true)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the code is trying to match the key in a dictionary, but the dictionary is empty or the key does not match. Can you provide  a little more information about the dictionary?
If the error is in that specific line, try **F11** key slowly all the way to the external library. This should give you an ide of what the code external code is looking for.

Comment: I don't create a dictionary why I'm having that error??